# Updating Database When Dataset Filled from View (not table)

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, ado.net, dataset

**Background**: I have a Windows Forms Application with a `DataGridView` control that is bound to a `DataSet`. The `DataSet` is filled with data from a database view. Some of the `DataGridView` cells are editable, and rows need to be delete-able.

**Problem**: When a value in the grid is edited, how do I update the database? It does not appear to be nearly as easy as it would be if it were pointing to a database table, rather than a view. Should I be adding the tables relevant to the view to the `DataSet` as well, and then making the appropriate changes to the tables and then calling the update `DataSet` method?

**Edit1**: I think `DataSets` that point to a view with joins cannot have the `Update()` method called.

**Edit2**: With the below code, I get an error saying:

> there is no definition for Update

when my `DataSet` looks at a view. However, if a `DataSet` points to a table, Update does exist. Both `DataSet` are autogenerated by VS. What am I doing wrong?

```
try
{
   this.ASSIGNMENTS_VWTableAdapter.Update(this.TEST_Dataset.ASSIGNMENTS_VW);            
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

**Edit3**: The following code is what I used to try the SqlCommandBuilder. I get the error I mentioned in my comment below "Dynamic SQL generation is not supported against multiple base tables."

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
    adapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM ASSIGNMENTS_VW", connection);
    SqlCommandBuilder builder = new SqlCommandBuilder(adapter);

    connection.Open();

    builder.GetUpdateCommand();

    adapter.Update(tEST_ASSIGNMENTS_VW, "ASSIGNMENTS_VW");
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful to see code snippets.

Comment: make changes to dataset then call update.  See following webpage : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommandbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Elyasin I saw this as more of a conceptual question. Pretty much all my code so far is auto-generated from the designer tools. In VS I add a datagridview to the form, I create a dataset using the wizard that points to my database view, and then VS does all the work setting things up.

Comment: @jdweng I think Update cannot be called for a dataset when its source is a view that contains joins.

Comment: Not true.  Only requirement and the connection contains four commands : Select, Insert, Update, and Delete.  The CommandBuilder takes the Select Command and automatically creates the Insert, Update, and Delete.  The Update command is built just like a database Update query and will work.

Comment: @jdweng I added some code to my initial post with Edit 2. Do you know what I'm not doing?

Comment: Also, if I try to use the SqlCommandBuilder, I get the following error message: "Dynamic SQL generation is not supported against multiple base tables."

Comment: Ado.net has no problems with updating views, as long as the view itself is updatable. You should create an instead of update trigger on your view.

Comment: The adapter will not have an update method until you apply the command builder to the sql command.  Look at the link I provided and add the command builder to the adapter.

Comment: @jdweng, I have added the code to my main post (Edit3) I used while attempting to use the SqlCommandBuilder. Thank you for your continued help!

Comment: The error message doesn't make any sense since you SQL doesn't have multiple tables.  I think the msdn webpage has been changed slightly.  I don't understand why the open is need.  I think the adapter fill automatically does the open.  I also don't understand why the GetUpdateCommand() is needed.  I think the error in your code is due to not having the adapter.fill() method which actually reads the database and sets the flags indicating if the datatable rows in the database have been updated.  You need adapter.fill(tEST_ASSIGNMENTS_VW)